# Сканирование набора символов scanf и []

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения, scanf

Зачем вообще может быть звёздочка в таких выражениях?

```
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

По поводу нижних всё ясно, но встретил выражение по типу верхнего и не могу понять зачем она необходима

```
scanf("%[a-z]", str);
scanf("%20[a-z]", str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` в синтаксисе `scanf` — это модификатор подавления ввода, т.е. `scanf` будет сопоставлять строку в соответствии с требованиями остальных операторов, но не будет записывать её ни в какой выходной буфер (внимание на отсутствие передаваемого указателя).

Код

```
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

По сути читает один символ из стандартного ввода только если он является `\n`, он эквивалентен, например, следующему:

```
int c;
if ( '\n' == (c=getc(stdin)) ) {
  ungetc (c, stdin);
}
```

Почитать про модификаторы `scanf()` можно в любой документации к libc (например в nix'овых [man'ах](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=scanf&category=3&russian=0#lbAE)) или любом хорошем современном букваре по языку Си (например [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Parameters)).

Answer (score 2):

Звездочка в `scanf` форматах означает "читать символы, но никуда не присваивать". Ваш

```
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

фактически означает "пропустить один символ, если этот символ является `\n`.

Очевидно, это предназначено для решения той часто встречающейся проблемы, когда автор кода подозревает, что во входном буфере может болтаться непрочитанный символ `\n`, и хочет его оттуда вычистить.

При этом надо иметь в виду, что даже в присутствии этой `*`, если очередной символ во входном потоке не соответствует требуемому формату, это расценивается как ошибка и приводит к немедленному завершению всего `scanf`. По этой причине спецификаторы, которые могут что-то прочитать, а могут ничего и не прочитать, зачастую выносят в отдельный `scanf`.